# How to use underscore headers with waitress?

Tags: python, wsgi, waitress

I've been working in a Flask project using waitress for production environement (Targeting Linux ARM and Windows), and I need to recieve a request from a service which has a headers like "dev_id" and "request_code" [(doc)](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:FHU6GxCqdi4J:https://wenku.baidu.com/view/0049a2a86aec0975f46527d3240c844769eaa019.html%20&cd=1&hl=pt-BR&ct=clnk&gl=br).

Waitress got a pull request in 2015 [(link)](https://github.com/Pylons/waitress/pull/129/commits/6d4dab6bed88917b973066a6d5222917661802b7) basically skipping headers containing `_`, which explains why the headers are not present in the request object.

- I've considered switching to Gunicorn, but Windows support is a must-have.
- Using flask as a self-WSGI works, but do not seems to be the perfect approach for a production environement.
- Using raw socket for HTTP instead of Flask sounds acceptable, but demands some work for refactoring.
- Changing the header name is not an option as I do not have access.

I want to read the header `dev_id` sent by my client in a Flask application, but waitress doesn't let me do that. Is there any way to ignore this rule? Any workarounds?

Comment: That pull request is more than three years old.  If that problem hasn't been fixed, then Waitress isn't probably worth sticking with.  Aren't there literally dozens of WSGI servers out there that run on Windows?  I know there are at least a few pure Python servers.  Assuming there's not some good reason technically for a WSGI server to not retain and pass along headers with underscores in their names, I'd look to switch to something else.

Comment: No success with gevent, twisted, uwsgi. I guess my best option would use the built-in.